# Run cron job every 5 min

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

This is my print.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
from datetime import datetime
fn = 'msgs.txt'                                                                 
f = open(fn, 'aw')
f.write('%s\n' % datetime.now())
f.close()
```

I want to run this silly script every 5 minutes. I did

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and added

```
*/5 * * * * /home/msh/sandbox/python/cron/run.sh
```

where run.sh is just

```
#!/bin/sh
python /home/msh/sandbox/python/cron/print.py
```

Files `run.sh` and `print.py` have executing permission.

However I don't see the script running because there is no input in `msgs.txt`.
Did I set up cron job correctly?

Comment: is python is your path?  have you check you cron logs

Comment: assuming ubuntu have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the full path to the target file in your cron script; this is to make sure you know where to check if its being written or not. Try changing `fn = 'msg.txt'` to `fn = '/home/msh/sandbox/python/cron/msg.txt'`

This isn't important in your simple example, but you aren't running the script with `python2.7`, you are running it with `python` (which may be a different version).

As you have marked the file as executable, your cron task should be simply `/home/msh/sandbox/python/cron/print.py`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in the absolute path.